# OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator - nonce error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, openid-connect, nonce

I'm using OpenIdConnect authentication on my azure website (azure active directory, c#, MVC) and I'm randomly getting this error

> IDX10311: requireNonce is true (default) but validationContext.Nonce
>   is null. A nonce cannot be validated.  If you dont need to check the
>   nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to false

I am using the KentorOwinCookieSaver which as far as I understand, was a solution to this problem, but obviously I'm wrong because it keeps on happening.  How can I stop this ?

In the ConfigureAuth method I have this line

```
app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
```

Answer (score 5):

According to your description, I followed this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/) and used this [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) to check this issue. The initialization for authentication middle ware would look as follows:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = context => 
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Using [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network traces when logging, you could find the OpenIdConnect.nonce cookie would be issued to the browser before the OpenID Connect middleware starting the authentication request as follows:

[image]

After user entered the credentials and consent the permissions, the `authorization_code`,`id_token`,`state` would be posted to your specified **RedirectUri**, then some validation would be executed and generate the new cookie and remove the previous OpenIdConnect.nonce cookie as follows:

[image]

> IDX10311: requireNonce is true (default) but validationContext.Nonce is null. A nonce cannot be validated. If you dont need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to false

I used [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect 3.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/3.0.1) to test this issue. Per my understanding, you need to make sure your OpenIdConnect.nonce cookie has been successfully issued to your browser. For example, if your cookie issued to `https://localhost:44353/`, while the RedirectUri is set to `http://localhost:4279`, then I would encounter the similar issue:

[image]

Or you could try to explicitly set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to false to disable check the nonce.

Comment: when we disable it, it produces different error. `IDX21329: RequireState is '[PII is hidden]' but the OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.State is null. State cannot be validated.`

Comment: we tried this by disabling state as well but still same error. `ProtocolValidator = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator() {RequireNonce = false, RequireState = false}`

Comment: In my case, I can see `OpenIdConnect.nonce` in browser but issue is I get this cors error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://devsafeplatformxxxx.b2clogin.com/devsafeplatformxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sign_in/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...' (redirected from 'https://www.xx.com/api/test/getdata') from origin 'https://www.xx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

- This is the "Katana bug", install Kentor.OwinCookieSaver from nuget
  package manager
- Add below lines inside the configuration method

  app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

**My complete config FYR:**

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        try
        {

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();                

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions()
            {
                OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"],
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"],
                AuthorizationServerId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:AuthorizationServerId"],
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"],
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
                Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email" },
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Error
        }
    }
```

**Solution 2:**

- Check whether you have SSL in your application if yes check whether
  binding happened properly.
- If application runs on http it'll cause this error.